# Using one hash reference rather than two in Perl

Tags: perl

Is there some way in Perl that I can mention k just once on the second line:

```
my %k = (a=>1, b=>2, c=>undef);
say for grep{!$k{$_}} keys %k;
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Make use of `mapp` and `grepp` as found in the CPAN module `List::Pairwise`:

```
use List::Pairwise qw(grepp mapp);
my %k = (a=>1, b=>2, c=>undef);
say for mapp { $a } grepp { !$b } %k;
```

Comment: But aware you must stay, not to have a my $a, or to use my $b in the near vicinity as it will destroy what is true without warning you.

Answer (score 4):

Yes:

```
$b or say $a while ($a,$b) = each %k
```

But that's not any better (worse, IMO), so I'd stick with what you have.

Comment: Your implementation sucks, but the idea (`each`) is good. `while (my ($k,$v) = each %k) { say $k if !$v; }` would be far more readable and maintainable without being substantially longer.

Answer (score 2):

Using `each`:

```
my %k = ( a => 1, b => 2, c => undef ); 
while ( my ($i, $j) = each %k ) { say $i unless $j };
```